# How can I convert a list of lists of numpy arrays to a more memory friendly format?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, out-of-memory

My question is related to the conversion of a list of `numpy` arrays to a more memory friendly format since I face memory errors.

This is the code I am using for the creation of the `output` variable (the list of numpy arrays):

```
#import of the libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

#definition of the variables       
numStations = 4

numLinesUnique = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 2],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])

traversals = [[[], [[]], [[1]], [[1, 2], [434, 435, 436, 437]]],
              [[[]], [], [[]], [[2]]],
              [[[1]], [[]], [], [[]]],
              [[[2, 1]], [[2]], [[]], []]]

#definition of the outpt variable
output = [[[] for x in range(numStations)] for x in range(numStations)]

#main code
for i in range(numStations):
    for j in range(numStations):
        if i!=j:
            t_numpyTraversals = np.zeros((numLinesUnique[i,j],5500)).astype(bool)            
            for k in range(numLinesUnique[i,j]):
                t_numpyTraversals[k,traversals[i][j][k]] = True
            output[i][j] = t_numpyTraversals
```

So, the `output` variable stores a list of lists of `boolean` numpy arrays with length of 5500. **Note** that 5500 is the original `numStations` in my code that's why I am getting memory error when I am trying to create the `output` variable.

I am using `numStations = 4` for the `for` loops as a reproducable example.

As you can see in the numpy arrays stored in the `output` variable few values are `True` .

So far I have tried to store in a `dict` only the `True` values by using the following code:

```
#redefine the output variable
output = [[[] for x in range(4)] for x in range(4)]

for i in range(numStations):
    for j in range(numStations):
        if i!=j:
           list_of_traversals_stops = []
           for k in range(numLinesUnique[i,j]):
             tempd = {} #create the dict to store the True values
             for kk in range(len(traversals[i][j][k])):
                    tempd[traversals[i][j][k][kk]] = True
           list_of_traversals_stops.append(tempd)
           output[i][j].append(list_of_traversals_stops)
```

This method is more memory efficient since the `output` variable does not hold many `False` values. However, the format of the `output` is not helping me to use it as an input to another function.

I am searching for an **alternative data structure** (similar to the original output - list of lists of numpy arrays) that is memory friendly and it can store the `False` values as well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

List of lists can work, but for memory-efficiency, you should be storing the **index** and not `True`/`False` values because you have to store 5500 boolean variables vs. only tracking the **index** that are `True`.

If you need an explicit index to boolean mapping, a dictionary can work (similar to your second code `output`), but it is not as friendly as just storing indexes without boolean values.

That being said, I think the most efficient format is actually the `traversals` variable that you define. You can retrieve `numLinesUnique` using

```
numLinesUnique = [[len(col) for col in row] for row in traversals]
```

I'm not sure what your `output` will be used for but it can definitely be derived from `traversals` which is more space efficient.

Also, in your second code snippet, I think `output` is wrong because for `output[0][3]` I only see one list, I believe it should have 2.

Comment: Thanks @KayJan for your response. Indeed, saving the index of the True value is more efficient. I am using the output as follows: np.vstack([output[0][i] for i in cxns]) where cxns is the number of the dictionary keys (1,2,434,435,436,437). Therefore, since I don't have the same length for the lists I cannot perform this command. Do you have any suggestion for that?